# extract values from columns based on another column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe `df` like the following:

```
                    Warehouse        Date                Count
0     Delhivery Goa Warehouse     2022-05-12                83
1     Delhivery Goa Warehouse     2022-05-15                 1
2     Delhivery Goa Warehouse     2022-05-18               100
3     Delhivery Tauru Warehouse   2022-05-19               100
4     Delhivery Tauru Warehouse   2022-05-20               100
```

and another dataframe `df_orig` like the following:

```
              index                          Goa    Tauru    
0     2022-05-12Delhivery Goa Warehouse     100.0     0.0   
1     2022-05-15Delhivery Goa Warehouse     100.0     0.0   
2     2022-05-18Delhivery Goa Warehouse     100.0     0.0   
3     2022-05-20Delhivery Tauru Warehouse    0.0     50.0   
4     2022-05-19Delhivery Tauru Warehouse    0.0     70.0
```

How can I pick values from the `df_orig` columns based on combination of warehouse and Date columns of the `df`?

Expected output:

```
                    Warehouse        Date                Count      original
0     Delhivery Goa Warehouse     2022-05-12                83       100
1     Delhivery Goa Warehouse     2022-05-15                 1       100
2     Delhivery Goa Warehouse     2022-05-18               100       100
3     Delhivery Tauru Warehouse   2022-05-19               100       70
4     Delhivery Tauru Warehouse   2022-05-20               100       50
```

My approach:

```py
df['index1'] = str(df['Date']) + str(df['Warehouse'])
original = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['index1'] == df_orig['index']:
        original.append(????)
```

Comment: You could use .merge() and merge on the index1 you create and the index in df_orig

Comment: @EmiOB I can but I want to pick values from only those column which matches name in the `index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate `Date` and `Warehouse` columns in first dataframe, and calculate the sum of values of all the columns except first using `iloc[:,1:]`, then merge two dataframes, and finally take only the columns of interest:

```py
(df
.assign(index=df['Date'] + df['Warehouse'])
.merge(df_orig.assign(original=df_orig.iloc[:,1:].sum(1)))
)[['Warehouse', 'Date', 'Count', 'original']]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                   Warehouse        Date  Count  original
0    Delhivery Goa Warehouse  2022-05-12     83     100.0
1    Delhivery Goa Warehouse  2022-05-15      1     100.0
2    Delhivery Goa Warehouse  2022-05-18    100     100.0
3  Delhivery Tauru Warehouse  2022-05-19    100      70.0
4  Delhivery Tauru Warehouse  2022-05-20    100      50.0
```

Comment: This works absolutely fine but what if columns in `df_orig` are dynamic, in future there could be more columns like Goa, Tauru, foo, bar, etc

Comment: @RahulSharma look at the updated answer

Comment: @RahulSharma Apparently you can also decide which columns you want to exclude `df_orig[[c for c in df_orig if c!='index']].sum(1)`

Answer (score 1):

`merge()` works here. You can also map the sum of the values in `df_orig` to `df` rows using `map()` method. As `index` column in `df_orig` is the same as the concatenation of `Date` and `Warehouse` columns in `df`, first concatenate those columns to make the mapping keys match.

```py
# map the sum of the values in df_orig to df.Warehouse via df_orig.index
df['original'] = (df['Date'].astype(str)+df['Warehouse']).map(df_orig.set_index('index').sum(1))
```

[image: res]